# Uniform convergence of Fourier series proof

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I want to prove that: **If $f(x)$ is continuous with a period of $2\pi$ and its derivative $f^\prime(x)$ is piecewise continuous, then the Fourier series of $f(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$.**

I'm familiar with the exact same proof (presented below) except for the fact that $f^\prime(x)$ has jump discontinuities.

Don't these discontinuities affect the uniform convergence of $f$ ? What changes in the proof if $f^\prime$ is piecewise continuous?

[image]

Comment: Is $f'$ piecewise smooth or piecewise continuous?

Comment: My mistake. I meant $f$ is piecewise smooth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof works all the same, with the caveat the definition of "piecewise smooth" only allows discontinuity jumps, and thus $f'\in L^2$.

At the very end of the proof,  it is not obvious to  me that $f$ is of bounded variation, but one can use the result that if $f$ is continuous and its Fourier series converges uniformly, then it equals $f$.